# Directional adjacency list fast implementation

Tags: python, cython, adjacency-list

```
import distance
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = ['ACAA', 'TCAA','TCAT','TGAT','TCGA','TGGA','GCGA','AAAA','GGGG','GGGC']
counts = {'ACAA':60, 'TCAA':3,'TCAT':30,'TGAT':8,'TCGA':1,'TGGA':1,'GCGA':8,'AAAA':5,'GGGG':8,'GGGC':1}

adj_list = defaultdict(list)
for strng1 in my_list:
    for strng2 in my_list:
        if distance.hamming(strng1, strng2) == 1 and counts[strng1] >= (counts[strng2]*2):
            adj_list[strng1].append(strng2)
```

I have this implementation for getting a directional adjacency list. Expected results:

```
ACAA: TCAA
TCAA: TCGA
TCAT: TCAA, TGAT
TGAT
TCGA: TGGA
TGGA: TCGA
GCGA: TCGA
AAAA
GGGG: GGGC
GGGC
```

Is there a faster implementation? This get very slow with large data sets. Would rewriting this in cython speed it up? If yes can someone help me get started with cython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Cython, but you could avoid accessing dict items in your inner loop:

```
adj_list = defaultdict(list)
for strng1 in my_list:
    a1 = adj_list[strng1]
    c1 = counts[strng1]
    for strng2 in my_list:
        if distance.hamming(strng1, strng2) == 1 and c1 >= (counts[strng2]*2):
            a1.append(strng2)
```

You could even cut more by iterating only on the second half and perform a symmetric append. That way you save 50% of the computation of the distance since it's symmetric. You only perform it on the upper matrix triangle (diagonal excluded, I suppose that distance of one string with itself is 0) instead of the full matrix.

```
for i,strng1 in enumerate(my_list):
    ...
    for j in range(i+1,len(my_list)):
```

My attempt, I'm not sure, but should be close:

```
adj_list = defaultdict(list)
for i,strng1 in enumerate(my_list):
    a1 = adj_list[strng1]
    c1 = counts[strng1]
    for j in range(i+1,len(my_list)):
        strng2 = my_list[j]
        if distance.hamming(strng1, strng2) == 1:
            c2 = counts[strng2]
            if c1 >= (c2*2):
                a1.append(strng2)
            if c2 >= (c1*2):
                adj_list[strng1].append(strng2)
```

**crysis405 Edit:**

Original:

```
def adj_lst(my_list, counts):
    adj_list = defaultdict(list)
    for strng1 in my_list:
        a1 = adj_list[strng1]
        c1 = counts[strng1]
        for strng2 in my_list:
            if distance.hamming(strng1, strng2) == 1 and c1 >= (counts[strng2]*2):
                adj_list[strng1].append(strng2)
```

Suggested improvement:

```
def adj_lst_fast(my_list, counts):
    adj_list_fast = defaultdict(list)
    for i,strng1 in enumerate(my_list):
        a1 = adj_list_fast[strng1]
        c1 = counts[strng1]
        for j in range(i+1,len(my_list)):
            strng2 = my_list[j]
            if distnace.hamming(strng1, strng2:
                c2 = counts[strng2]
                if c1 >= (c2*2):
                    adj_list_fast[strng1].append(strng2)
                elif c2 >= (c1*2):
                    adj_list_fast[strng2].append(strng1)
```

Performance:

```
print(timeit.timeit('adj_lst(my_list, counts)', number = 10000, 
setup="from __main__ import adj_lst, my_list, counts"))
```

1.2892486669989012

```
print(timeit.timeit('adj_lst_fast(my_list, counts)', number = 10000, 
setup="from __main__ import adj_lst_fast, my_list, counts"))
```

0.6437049919986748

Comment: @crysis405 huge thumbs up for your excellent edit that proves my point :) we need more editors like you.